# How Does sys.stdin.read() Change the Structure of a Literal Parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

**Backstory:** In my previous post, I was wondering if a certain function was valid to replace another function and it was, so, I technically don't need an answer to help with with my project but I was just wondering *"had I continued using sys.stdin.read() instead of input(), how would I get through one of my roadblocks?"*

**My issue:** For some reason, when I used sys.stdin.read() it did not work with literal strings or chars. This is a lazy but working reconstruction of my code...

```
print("Type p or P for a pyramid")
print("Type s or S for the sum and product of two numbers")
choice_1 = sys.stdin.read()

# edge case for inputted char being invalid
if str(choice_1) != ('p' or 'P' or 's' or 'S')
    err_test = 'z'
    while str(err_test) != ('p' or 'P' or 's' or 'S')
        print("Invalid option!)
        print("Type p or P for a pyramid")
        print("Type s or S for the sum and product of two numbers"
        err_test = sys.stdin.read()
        if err_test == ('p' or 'P' or 's' or 'S')
            break
```

This code is roughly what I wrote. I am not writing this question at home so I couldn't copy it word for word. If you see any problems at all, please list them out, whether it's a syntax error or frowed-upon-formatting. I want to learn as much as possible but please, if you have any idea why the line right below the comment (line 6) doesn't work, please let me know! Thanks!

**Edit: ** Thank you so much for the feedback! I forgot to mention though, at one point, I tried isolating the problem so I created a new python file and created a loop that lasted forever and tested it out with only one character. I'll make it super simplified:

```
char = sys.stdin.read()
if char == 'a':
    print("This works!")
if char != 'a':
    print("This failed!)
```

Even this code ^^^ didn't work! Please let me know why. –

Comment: it has to be `err_test != 'p' or err_test != 'P' or err_test != 's' or err_test != 'S'` or you can do `err_test not in ('p', 'P', 's', 'S')` and with `lower()`/`upper()` even shorter `err_test.lower() not in ('p', 's')`. And `sys.stdin.read()` always gives string so you don't need `str()`. And if you want to check single char then you could use `read(1)`

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. However, when I tried to implement the distributed '!=' sign, it still doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Edit: I TRIED IT, IT WORKS!

Comment: it seems you resolved problem - I could only say: first use `print(...)`,`print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))` to check if you have the same values in variables.

Comment: Yes, well actually, sort of. The thing is, it works some of the time and it doesn't for the rest. I can't seem to figure out why! I don't desperately need an answer to this but it would be really nice to know because I am beyond frustrated and confused. I cant find a way to post code through comments so do you, by any chance, have a Discord account that I can send my code file to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test for "matches one of several accepted strings" is wrong in a similar way to [this question's mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/364696); it's not quite the same due to the use of parentheses, but in this case, both of your tests are equivalent to testing `leftside != 'p'`, because `or` chains evaluate to the first truthy value, or the last value if all are falsy, and any non-empty string is truthy, so the parenthesized grouping simplifies to just `'p'`. You wanted `leftside in ('p', 'P', 's', 'S')` (or perhaps slightly faster on modern Python, which optimizes tests against `set` literals of literals to construct an equivalent `frozenset` at compile time and reuse it, allowing `O(1)` average case lookup, rather than `O(n)` `tuple` scan work, `leftside in {'p', 'P', 's', 'S'}`).

Additionally, `input` will read one line, strip the newline, and return it, while `sys.stdin.read()` consumes the *entirety* of stdin on the first call (all lines), leaving it empty, so trying to call it again will not receive anything. If you *can't* use `input` for some reason, either of `next(sys.stdin).rstrip('\n')` or `sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')` will be roughly equivalent to plain `input()` (`input` is more powerful in some ways, e.g. it has `readline` integration, but it's close).

Lastly, a minor note: There's no reason to do `str(choice_1)` or `str(err_test)` (they're already `str`, so wrapping in `str` is pointless).

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! I forgot to mention though, at one point, I tried isolating the problem so I created a new python file and created a loop that lasted forever and tested it out with only one character. I'll make it super simplified:

char = sys.stdin.read()
if char == 'a':
    print("This works!")
if char != 'a':
    print("This failed!")

Even this code ^^^ didn't work! Please let me know why.

Comment: @xCqlibur: Because, as noted, `sys.stdin.read()` reads *all* of stdin, not just one line, and it would include any newlines. So if all you type is `a<Enter>`, then Ctrl-D to end stdin, it still returns `'a\n'` which won't match. Instead of testing against `char`, just do `print(repr(char))` and you'll see what the string literal equivalent of what you read is. Read the documentation of the `io` module to get a better idea of what these methods do; `sys.stdin.read()` is usually not what you want unless you're assuming the program is being invoked piping a file in as stdin.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I might have used ...readline() though, I forgot. Will that affect anything?

Comment: @xCqlibur: Of course it will. That reads just a line, like `input()` (again, read the `io` docs; random guessing at what APIs do or copy-pasting random code from the internet is not the way to write code). But it doesn't strip the newline. See my suggestions, I already provided roughly equivalent code.